# How can I make the OSSEC server service start automatically on reboot?

Tags: centos7, ossec

I am running CentOS7 with OSSEC 2.9.2.  Is there a way to make OSSEC automatically start the server after a reboot?  Currently it appears to require that I run the ossec-control start after every reboot.

Answer (score 3):

To run OSSEC as a service create a new file /usr/lib/system/system/ossec.service

```
[Unit]
Description=OSSEC service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control start
ExecStop=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemd

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

To boot on start up

```
systemctl enable ossec
```

To start ossec as a service

```
service ossec start
service ossec stop
```

Comment: Aren't local unit files supposed to go in `/etc` somewhere?

Comment: One should not create this file under `/usr/lib...`. User provided service files, as well as service.d's belong to `/etc/systemd/system`